# Custom ControlBox events for every form in VB project, placed into a Module

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

In every form of a project I am working on, there are some `FlowLayoutPanel`s which contain three `Label`s. Those `Label`s work as **Minimize**, **Maximize** and **Close** form buttons. In other words an own **Form Control Box**.

In every form there is a `Private Sub` like the one below, which is called by custom buttons events:

```
Private Sub AllForms_CustomControlBox_Controls_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim _Label = DirectCast(sender, Control)
    If _Label.Name = "Custom_MinimizeForm_Label" Then
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    ElseIf _Label.Name = "Custom_MaximizeForm_Label" Then
        If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal Then
            Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        ElseIf Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized Then
            Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        End If
    ElseIf _Label.Name = "Custom_CloseForm_Label" Then
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

In order to avoid to repeat this part of code in every form, I thought it would be better to place it once into a module. I have tried to convert this part of code as it should be in a module, but with no success. When I click on any of the three `Label`s, I get this message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'

```
Public Sub AllForms_CustomControlBox_Controls_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    For Each _Form As Form In My.Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of Form)()
        For Each _FlowLayoutPanel As Control In _Form.Controls.OfType(Of FlowLayoutPanel)()
            For Each _Label As Control In _FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
                If _Label.Name = "Custom_MinimizeForm_Label" Then
                    _Form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
                ElseIf _Label.Name = "Custom_MaximizeForm_Label" Then
                    If _Form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal Then
                        _Form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
                    ElseIf _Form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized Then
                        _Form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
                    End If
                ElseIf _Label.Name = "Custom_CloseForm_Label" Then
                    _Form.Close()
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This occurs because you are using a for...each loop and modifying the things within the loop. Try using a for...next loop with step -1 to work through the loop backwards.

Comment: You don't want a module.  You want a UserControl.

Comment: @peterG: Can you give me an example?

Comment: @LarsTech: I know my friend, I just don't have the time to make a UserControl for this!!!

Comment: Just copy your FlowLayoutPanel with the child controls into a UserControl.  Hook up the click events.  A UserControl has a property called "ParentForm" you can use to access your window state information.  It would make your project code much cleaner.  It's unclear from your example code why pressing any of the buttons should perform actions on all your forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original code that you had in each form is good. You don't need the loop and other modifications that you added to it.

All you needed to do is replace the `Me` with `_Label.FindForm()`, and of course make it `Public` like you did:

```
Public Sub AllForms_CustomControlBox_Controls_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim _Label = DirectCast(sender, Control)
    Dim _Form = _Label.FindForm()
    If _Label.Name = "Custom_MinimizeForm_Label" Then
        _Form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    ElseIf _Label.Name = "Custom_MaximizeForm_Label" Then
        If _Form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal Then
            _Form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        ElseIf Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized Then
            _Form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        End If
    ElseIf _Label.Name = "Custom_CloseForm_Label" Then
        _Form.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I get this error: `'_Form' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.`

Comment: Sorry, I meant `_Label`, not `_Form`. See my updated answer.